# How to reproduce a graph plotting numerical X over a categorical Y with multiple levels using ggplot or plotly?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, r-plotly

I want to plot in R using ggplot or another package a graph showing levels of a categorical Y over a numerical X.

I would appreciate your help to do so and have attached a sample Figure by [Akseer et al](http://www.thelancet.com/journals/langlo/article/PIIS2214-109X(16)30002-X/abstract) of what the graph I want to draw. [image].

#### Here is sample data to reproduce this Figure.

Data for Figure A:

```
Interventions<-c("CPR", "ANC 1+","ANC 4+", "SBA","Caesarian section",
          "Early breastfeeding", "Exclusive breastfeeding at 6 months","BCG", "DTP3",
          "OPV3", "Measles vaccine",
          "Fully immunised", "Vitamin A+", "ORT",
          "Pneumonia care", "Improved water",
          "Sanitation")

Poorest<- (1/5)*(sample(1:100, 17, replace=TRUE))
Poorer<-(2/5)*(sample(1:100, 17, replace=TRUE))
Middle<-(3/5)*(sample(1:100, 17, replace=TRUE))
Richer<-(4/5)*(sample(1:100, 17, replace=TRUE))
Richest<-sample(1:100, 17, replace=TRUE)

mydata_A<-data.frame(Interventions, Poorest,Poorer, Middle, Richer, Richest)
rownames(mydata_A) <- mydata_A[,1]
dtFig3A<- mydata_A[,-1]
```

Comment: How about you split your question into two (you're asking for two very different figures)?

Comment: That's fine. I can divide it into two questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of the first graph: First rearange the data to long format and use `geom_point` and `geom_errorbarh` to do the actual mapping. The rest is just makeup.

```
library(tidyverse)

dtFig3A %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  gather(key, value, 2:6) %>% #convert to long format
  mutate(key = factor(key, levels = c("Poorest", #relevel key factor
                                      "Poorer",
                                      "Middle",
                                      "Richer",
                                      "Richest"))) %>%
  group_by(rowname) %>%
  mutate(min = min(value),
         max = max(value)) %>% #calculate min and max in each group for errorbarh
  ggplot()+
  geom_errorbarh(aes(y = rowname,
                     xmin = min,
                     xmax = max,
                     group = key),
                 height = 0) +
  geom_point(aes(y = rowname,
                 x = value,
                 fill = key),
             color = "grey20",
             shape = 21,
             size = 3) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        legend.title = element_blank())+
  ylab("Intervention")+
  xlab("Coverage [%]") +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "seq",
                    palette = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Terrific! Thanks for this, @missuse.